# RabbitMQ "access to vhost 'OWN' refused"

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

As you can see, I try to set and use permission on new vhost on RabbitMQ. I cannot find out, what's my problem. If I use vhost as "/", all worked ok.

```
=INFO REPORT==== 18-Nov-2016::11:50:20 ===
Setting permissions for 'mqadmin' in '/' to '.*', '.*', '.*'

=INFO REPORT==== 18-Nov-2016::11:50:24 ===
Setting permissions for 'mqadmin' in '/OWN' to '.*', '.*', '.*'

=INFO REPORT==== 18-Nov-2016::11:51:49 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.18046.18> (my_ip:60527 -> server_ip:5671)

=ERROR REPORT==== 18-Nov-2016::11:51:49 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.18046.18> (my_ip:60527 -> server_ip:5671, user: 'mqadmin', state: opening):
access to vhost 'OWN' refused for user 'mqadmin'

=INFO REPORT==== 18-Nov-2016::11:51:49 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.18046.18> (my_ip:60527 -> server_ip:5671)
```

ConnectionUrl on node.js/amqps is

```
var connectUrl = sprintf('amqps://%s:%s@%s/%s', 'mqadmin', 'my_password', 'server_ip','OWN');
```

Answer (score 3):

I answered to myself. Solved! vhost "/OWN" and "OWN" are not the same! When ignoring / from vhost, all worked ok.

Comment: good catch! standard convention is to use / in front of vhost name, though this is not strictly required